# How can I return a value from GM_xmlhttprequest?

Tags: variables, greasemonkey, global-variables, alert, undefined

I have this code here:

```
var infiltrationResult;

while(thisOption) {
    var trNode = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdNode = document.createElement('td');
    var hrefNode = document.createElement('a');

    infPlanetID = thisOption.getAttribute('value');

  var myURL = "http://www.hyperiums.com/servlet/Planetinf?securitylevel=90&newinfiltr=New+infiltration&planetid=" + PlanetID + "&infplanetid=" + infPlanetID;

    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: myURL,
        headers: {
            'User-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
            'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
        },
        onload: function(responseDetails) {
                if (responseDetails.responseText.match(/<b>Invalid order<\/td><\/tr><tr><td><BR><center><font color=#AAAA77 face=verdana,arial size=2>The target planet is blocking all infiltrations[\s\S]<BR><BR>/im)) {
                    // Successful match
                    infiltrationResult = 'Invalid Order';
                } else {
                    // Match attempt failed
                    infiltrationResult = 'Infiltration Successfully Created';
                }
        }
    });
```

When I add

> alert(infiltrationResult);

right after it is assigned, I correctly see the string.

However, after the function has exited, I have try the same alert and I get:

```
undefined
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The request runs asynchronously. That's *why* the function takes an `onload` callback function in the first place. If it were synchronous, then `GM_xmlhttpRequest` would simply return the response details like an ordinary function.

While waiting for the request to return, the code after the call to `GM_xmlhttpRequest` continues running. Your script correctly identifies that `infiltrationResult` is undefined because the request hasn't completed yet.

If you need to do more than just assign the variable when the request comes back, then do that in the `onload` callback.

Comment: You were absolutely right.  Moving the code that monkeyed with that result into the function fixed everything.

Thanks!

G-Man

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var infiltrationResult;

while(thisOption) {
    var trNode = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdNode = document.createElement('td');
    var hrefNode = document.createElement('a');

    infPlanetID = thisOption.getAttribute('value');

  var myURL = "http://www.hyperiums.com/servlet/Planetinf?securitylevel=90&newinfiltr=New+infiltration&planetid=" + PlanetID + "&infplanetid=" + infPlanetID;

    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: myURL,
        headers: {
            'User-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
            'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
        },
        onload: function(responseDetails) {
                        if (responseDetails.responseText.match(/<b>Invalid order<\/td><\/tr><tr><td><BR><center><font color=#AAAA77 face=verdana,arial size=2>The target planet is blocking all infiltrations[\s\S]<BR><BR>/im)) {
                                // Successful match
                                infiltrationResult = 'Invalid Order';
                        } else {
                                // Match attempt failed
                                infiltrationResult = 'Infiltration Successfully Created';
                        }
                        sentback(infiltrationResult);//Sent it when it loads only
        }
    });

function sentback(x){
    alert(x);
}
```