# Is there a way to pass a value TO GM_xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

As indicated here:

[How can I return a value from GM_xmlhttprequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525243/how-can-i-return-a-value-from-gmxmlhttprequest)

I have a script that is asynchronous.  I would like to pass a value INTO this function so that when the onload function is called I can use it to display in the web page.

The challenge I'm having is that this value will change each time I pass it into the function.

So, for instance if I passed in 'abc', 'def', 'xyz'.

I would end up with

```
xyz
xyz
xyz
```

instead of

```
abc
def
xyz
```

So, my question is, how would I pass a value into this function so that each call of the function knows what to display when it's done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99927/oo-javascript-definitive-explanation-of-variable-scope/101089#101089):-

```
var urls = {"abc": "http://somehost/aurl",
           "def": "http://somehost/otherurl",
           "ghi": "http://someotherhost/aurl" }

for (var k in urls)
{

    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urls[k],
        onload: function(text) {
            return  function(xhr) {
                //Do stuff with xhr responseText etc and the text parameter
                alert(text)
            }
        }(k)
    }
}
```

This will alert "abc", "def" and "ghi" after each outstanding request completes.

Comment: What's the syntax for multiple parameters? Do you just add a comma after the k?

e.g. 
}(k,x)

Comment: Also, I was unable to edit a correction, but there is a missing `)`.  I think it goes right after the `}` in the line of code just above the last line.

Comment: Could someone explain how the `}(k)` near the end works ... for example, is `(k)` how the `GM_xmlhttpRequest`'s  `onload` passes the value of `k` back to the `for` loop? I am also confused by the `return function(xhr){alert(text)}`. Specifically, I don't understand the need for the function; e.g. why isn't that line of code simply `alert(text)`?